# Get Sequence Name (Oracle)?

Tags: java, database, oracle, sequence

I don't have access to see the database, but I have the ability to create database objects (via an xml file). The xml documentation says that if I set an attribute called "identity" to true then a sequence will be created. Is it possible for me to write logic that would return the name of the sequence so that I can use nextVal when I'm writing INSERT statements?

Robert

Here's the [documentation](http://www.edugarage.com/display/BBDN/Schema+Definitions), do a find on the word "identity"...

Comment: I'm going to add here, if you are going to be doing development for this blackboard application, as it appears that you will be doing, you might want to request access to the database directly.  If you can see the configuration for blackboard, and you can download sqldeveloper, try to use the blackboard connection parameters, then you might be able to login directly to the database so that it is easier to debug issues like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can run select statements, then you might be able to try select * from user_sequences to get the names of sequences.  Otherwise, could you please send the documentation for this database creation utility that you are using, if it is public.  Otherwise, it will be very difficult to answer this question.

EDIT:

After a review of the documentation, it said that if you created a table with a primary key, it would create a sequence with the following rules, quoted directly from the documentation:

> Primary keys must contain one columnref subelement that includes a single attribute, name, that references the column name to include in the primary key. In SQL Server, the key is mapped as an identity field with an auto-incremented value. On Oracle, a sequence is automatically created with the table name plus _seq suffix.

Thus, your query would be:

```
select * from all_sequences where sequence_name = upper(tablename || '_SEQ');
```

Comment: +1 This is exactly what was writing up too. To select from user_sequences table.

Comment: Please be sure that you are granted an access to Oracle data dictionary

Comment: I still feel like it is most important that we know what the utility is that he is using here, if it is publicly available in some way shape or form, or if at least the documentation is available.

Comment: By default, an oracle user is granted access to the USER_* views.

Comment: @Horus I've added a link to the documentation

Comment: btw, in that code I listed above, I hope that the value 'tablename' is obvious as the name of the table that you asked to be created.

Comment: @Horus Thank you. I got so caught up in trying to figure out the sequence, I didn't even think to keep READING. Again, thank you and I'm going to talk to the administrator tomorrow about getting direct access and sql developer.

Comment: sqldeveloper is free, and it freezes up a lot, but it is somewhat essential if you don't have access to licenses for better stuff.  Link here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html